# Jquery add and remove class using slider

Tags: jquery, styles, slider, apply

I have the below code for slider and now I need to add and remove css for an element using the max and min value.

This is what I have:

```
   $( "#audioslider" ).slider({
        orientation: "vertical",
        range: "min",
        min: 0,
        max: 100,
        value: 60,
        slide: function( event, ui ) {
            var value = $("#audioslider").slider("value");
            document.getElementById("audio").volume = (value / 100);
            if(value == 0){
            $('.volumeon').addClass('volumeoff')
            }else if(value >= "max"){
            $('.volumeon').addClass('volumeon')
            }
        }
    });
```

And If it's min its adding the class but not adding if its greater than min value.
So how do I do that?

Comment: If you add a class of volumeon to .volumeon, it won't do anything because the class would have to be there in order for you to select the element. You need to remove the 'off' class instead.

Comment: @Matthew-I have tried that way too but either it did not apply.

Comment: Sorry guys! I had a problem with vertical slider and I have changed it to horizontal.Now it's working fine.

Answer (score 1):

You mean this way ?

```
if(value < 1){
    $('.volumeon').addClass('volumeoff');
    $('.volumeon').removeClass('volumeon');
 }else {
    $('.volumeoff').addClass('volumeon');
    $('.volumeoff').removeClass('volumeoff');
 }
```

Comment: @safarov-Your's is near to the way but it was something messy that once it applied and the other time it dosen't.

Answer (score 1):

It looks mostly like a typo -- you are comparing `value` with the text "max" and not a variable.  Just change that line to

`}else if (value == 100){`

Comment: @Andy-You're right I tried to apply that but it ddn't worked and later changed to this way but this too was the same.

Answer (score 1):

Seems like the logic is a bit off.

Volume is on if the value is >= 100, but off if it's 0?  Wouldn't volume be on if it's greater than 0?

As Andy mentioned, you're comparing the var value to a string 'max' and not the actual intended max which is a property of slider.

In any case with the given logic.  You'll want to do a remove class on 'volumeOn' and add the 'volumeOff' class when the value is equal to 0.  In the case when value >= 100, you'll want to do the opposite, remove 'volumeOff' and add 'volumeOn'.

Essentially this bit of code.

```
if(value == 0){
  $('.volumeon').addClass('volumeoff').removeClass('volumeon');
} else if(value >= 100){
  $('.volumeoff').addClass('volumeon').removeClass('volumeoff');
}
```